# Scraping graph data from a web using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, graph

Is it possible to capture the graph data from a website? For example the website [here](http://www.mahallemistanbul.com/MahallemSEGE_/), has a graph.

I want to get the information in the chart below.

Is is possible to capture these data using Python code?

[image]

I wrote this code but I couldn't progress. I couldn't find the part with the graph.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL='http://www.mahallemistanbul.com/MahallemSEGE_/'
page=requests.get(URL)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what exactly you want to extract. share what you want. share if you have tried anything .

Comment: @iamtrappedman I edited my question. I want to get the information in the chart.

Comment: the data you want is loaded by JavaScript. try selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datas you are looking for are coming from an **external resource**.

They are not in the html query showed, but are integrated in the page through javascript.

You would need to get the **raw datas** from this other resource (check the network tab of your browser) or use an emulator such as :

- https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer
- https://playwright.dev/

Comment: Yes, data not in the html query showed. Thank you for your answer. I found the data in csv format in the network section. I'm wondering if I can reach it by doing web-scraping in python. I'll go through the resources you posted for this.

Comment: Yes you can do this in python

1) right click the query from the network

2) copy as curl 

3) convert from curl to request (https://curlconverter.com/)

4) get python code